# WebResourceResponse can't read full inputstream from HttpConnection (Android)

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

I'm working with an ionic application(like hybrid) which can play some videos.I want to add some headers to the request so that I override the "shouldInterceptRequest".

```java
URL myUrl = new URL(real);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
for (Map.Entry < String, String > entry: headers.entrySet()) {
  connection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
WebResourceResponse response = new WebResourceResponse("video/mp4", "UTF-8", in );
for (Map.Entry < String, List < String >> entry: connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
  resHeaders.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(0));
}
```

This code can't work.The video tag in html can't play the video.
So I add some code.

```java
byte[] bytes = new byte[30 * 1024 * 1024];
ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
  byteBuffer.write(bytes, 0, len);
}
bytes = byteBuffer.toByteArray();
WebResourceResponse response = new WebResourceResponse("video/mp4", "UTF-8", new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

When I read inputstream into bytes and send bytes to WebResourceResponse, the video can be play.However it means my application will use lots of memory if the video is large.

So that, I want to know is there any way to play the video without saving inputstream into bytes.

Answer (score 0):

OK.Fianlly,I found my way.
Actually, my goal is to add custom headers to resource request and now I found there is an easier way to do it.
For example, if I want to load a image,I will use img tag like this,`<img src="the_url_of_image">`,and I can't add any header to the request unless I interecept the request.
However,we can use `blob` now.We can request the resource by using something like ajax and use `createObjectURL` to create a url links to the resource.