# Sending HttpURLConnection inputStream to WebResourceResponse not resulting in proper response for WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I'm trying to append the cors headers to a request made in an Android webview by a JavaScript fetch command in order to bypass cors. To do this I'm intercepting requests made in the WebView with the shouldInterceptRequest member function.
The code I have seems to be working except that the stream I'm getting from the HttpURLConnection doesn't seem to work with the stream required by the WebResourceResponse. The relevant code (inside shouldInterceptRequest function):

```
val url = URL("https://www.android.com")
val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
try {
    var headers =
        urlConnection.headerFields.mapValues { it.value.joinToString() }
    headers = headers.toMutableMap()
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true"

    // val inStream: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.inputStream) // Doesn't work
    // val string = "hello world :)"
    // val inStream = string.byteInputStream(charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")) // Works when used as stream, sends "hello world :)" as response

    return WebResourceResponse(
        headers["Content-Type"],
        if (urlConnection.contentEncoding === null) "UTF-8" else urlConnection.contentEncoding,
        urlConnection.responseCode,
        "OK",
        headers,
        urlConnection.inputStream
    )
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect()
}
```

The last argument of the WebResourceResponse needs to be a stream which will be sent to the Webview page. When using the urlConnection.inputStream I can see in Chrome devtools that the headers are set properly on the response, but the data fails to load.

[image: Image showing error happening in WebView]

When I replace the response stream with a string the solution works fine, and the webview receives the string correctly. My question is then why doesn't the stream from the HttpURLConnection work when given to the response object, and how do I make it work.
The solution I'm looking for should not only support text, but also binary data and streams.

As a side note I've also tried implementing the requestIntercept asynchronously, as mentioned here: [How to get WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest invoked asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370123/how-to-get-webviewclient-shouldinterceptrequest-invoked-asynchronously), which changes the stream given to the response object, however this resulted in a very slow request followed by an android crash after the data had loaded and the request was done.

This isn't a duplicate of [WebResourceResponse can't read full inputstream from HttpConnection (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332992/webresourceresponse-cant-read-full-inputstream-from-httpconnection-android), the problem is different and the solution wouldn't work.

Entire code file: https://gist.github.com/RuurdBijlsma/2b52d80a4d74460ac2837ee55b0b933c in case that's helpful.

Comment: What is 'cors'?

Comment: @blackapps it's "cross-origin resource sharing" this website explains it https://enable-cors.org/. In short, on a web browser (or webview) you can't http request things from other domains, unless the target server specifically has this set up. However when making the request from the Android app no such limitation exists

Comment: @RuteNL Did you find a solution?

Comment: @BalaR no I did it eventually by using my server to proxy the request